# Configuring Git for the following scenario

Tags: git, version-control

I want to configure Git for the following scenario.

I have Puppet installed in /etc/puppet. For all the Puppet code inside /etc/puppet/modules, I want to initialize the Git to track the changes, but since by default nobody will be allowed to push to that directory, it creates problem. How can I do it so that all users can push the Puppet configuration code to /etc/puppet/modules?

Comment: why are you developing in /etc in the first place? this is hardly a Git question..

Comment: @benzaita: I want to add the puppet conf files in the git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would say:

1. setup remote bare repo somewhere else, make it available via SSH or git protocol (name it mainline)
2. setup clone of it in /etc/pupet/modules
3. Users should clone from mainline and push to mainline
4. If you want automatic update of /etc/puppet/module - setup cron job that will pull master branch every 10 min

much safer, more flexible and less headache.

Comment: I tried doing the above method, and was able to do also. But when I added post-receive hook to replace the 4th step, it told permission denied. I can do git checkout in post-receive hook but not able to do git pull. Can you help me in this.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I follow the logic here. Could you please clarify what have you done and why and how you're trying to change step 4 to a post-receive hook.